# One website multiple stores in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Please help me on this.
How can i create mutiple stores in with a single installation of magento. It's not like what you are thinking.

> Suppose my website is www.pstall.com, In the tech store it will be
>   tech.pstall.com or the flower shop it will be flower.pstall.com with
>   the help of sub domain. The shops order will be in their store's
>   admin. they will not share any data but they will share customer's
>   login. So that a customer can log in  every store with same id and
>   pass. I will use a static page for the mother store. So that customer ca n easily visit the stores. The sub stores
>   will be children. The stores won;t share any data even admin. Just
>   customer information and login.
>   Please help me how can i do that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in several ways:

1. create many websites
2. create many stores on one website (then you will have store switcher)
3. create many store views (then you will have Language switcher)

you don't have any restrictions here, but just need to set Base Url for each website/store/store view.
I would like to recommend you a #1 way and create websites. as later you maybe would like to show some of sites in 2 languages

here I did the same:
    http://innativelife.com/
    http://body.innativelife.com/
    http://soul.innativelife.com/

and also some store can have dedicated domain
    http://www.rastrat.net/

but will be placed on same admin

the only issue is that Magento CE not support admin separation per store. which mean - each admin will see data from all stores. But I know how to resolve it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..
[Creating multiple store in a single website](https://www.properhost.com/members/knowledgebase/30/How-to-Setup-Magento-with-Multiple-Stores-and-Domains.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Magento Multistore are created with 
--one website and many stores or
--Multiple websites with each having one or more then one store.

Setup will depend on what all you want to share and what you do not want to share.
Domains can be subdomains(store1.site.com) or same domain(site.com/store1) or totally different individual domains.

To share customer across stores you need to create one website but mulitple stores within that website.